# fwrite doesn`t write anything

Tags: php, html, fwrite

I am working on a comment meganism. If you leave a comment, it`ll be saved in a .txt file on the server.

he first problem was that I couldn`t find the file that it was saving the comments in. I dont know why, but it works now. The second problem was that it didnt write anything in the comment.txt file. The user fils in a form that links to this bit of code inside a seperate file called 'submitComment.php' This is my code:

```
<?php
    $fileName = "comments/thing1.txt";
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $theComment = $_POST['resentie'];
        $myfile = fopen($fileName, "a+");
        $whatToWrite = $name . PHP_EOL . $theComment;  //this is what it needs to write.
        fwrite($myfile, $whatToWrite);

        fclose($fileName);
    };
    ?>
```

I want it to say something like this.

> Alex 
> Hey, this is a comment.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: error_reporting, path relation, file permissions?

Comment: This bit of code is inside a folder called 'php'. The file with the forum isn`t inside any folder. I don`t get an error. And I think that I have all the permissions needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `fclose` on the filename string (`$fileName`) but it needs to be passed the file handle (`$myfile`):

```
<?php
$fileName = "comments/thing1.txt";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $theComment = $_POST['resentie'];
    $myfile = fopen($fileName, "a+");
    $whatToWrite = $name.PHP_EOL.$theComment;  //this is what it needs to write.
    fwrite($myfile, $whatToWrite);

    fclose($myfile); // <- This line is changed
};
?>
```

It would be a good idea to set up error reporting to help you debug programs.

- [error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting)
- [display_errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)

PHP outputs an error like this for your original code:

`Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /path/to/php/file on line 9`